# Where does the customer_email column get populated from in the sales_flat_order table in Magento on onepage checkout?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, checkout

I am trying to find the PHP code within Magento of where the customer_email column is populated after a successful transaction within the sales_flat_order table on the onepage checkout. In this instance I am checking out as a 'guest'.

For some reason the customer_email column isn't getting populated but only when I do a guest checkout on our staging server (seems to work on my vagrant box though which is odd??)

I know the code will be something like :-

```
$this->setCustomerEmail(); // or something like this
```

Comment: check you logs if you find anything or enable ini_set('display_errors') in index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is taken from the billing address.
Checkout controller in `saveOrderAction()` calls `$this->getOnepage()->saveOrder();` this goes to `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::_prepareGuestQuote()` method which sets email in quote from billing address.

Next the quote is copied to order in `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder()` method with this piece of code

```
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $this->getQuote());
    $service->submitAll();
```

And email is copied to order in 
`Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::submitOrder()` method with this piece of code

```
foreach ($this->_orderData as $key => $value) {
    $order->setData($key, $value);
}
```